# powerbi change column in matrix based on filter

Tags: conditional-statements, powerbi

I am a beginner in powerbi so please be patience.
I have a dataset in long format with few numerical `(LOCAL_MHRS, Percentage,...)` columns and some categorical columns `(Curve, class,...)`

Now I want a matrix visualization where `class` is used as index, the first columns is the `Percentage` for `Curve=A` and the second column is  `Percentage` for `Curve=X` where `X` is selected in a filter.

Is there any way to do that?  I have seen it in another visualization.

**EXAMPLE:**
Here an example where the Forecast columns change based on the selected Reference Curve in the filter. While the actual and planned columns show the values for `curve=actual` and `curve=planned`

[image]

Comment: Please share screenshots of what you have and what your expected result should look like @Donbeo?

Comment: I have added an example. This is from a pbi that  makes what I want but I can't replicate it

Comment: now I understand what you are looking for, however, I do not understand by what you mean RE curve=A & curve=X as I do not know what your data looks like...

Please share screenshots of your data and try to explain as much as possible, which will make it easier for us to give you an answer...